# Where/how to create new object in loop

Tags: java, loops, object

Say that I have a textfile that Im looping through each line in. The text files lines look like this:

```
1
2
3
4

1
2
3
4

1
2
3
4
```

I also have a class called DataHolder that I want a new instance of with each segment (where a segment is the lines 1 2 3 4). The DataHolder class has variables for 1 2 3 and 4. When the iterator hits the whitespace, a new object of the DataHolder class should be created for the next 1 2 3 4.

How can I accomplish this ? This is what I have at the moment

```
File theFile = new File(pathToFile);
try
{
    Scanner fileContent = new Scanner(theFile);
    DataHolder data = new DataHolder();
    while(fileContent.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = fileContent.nextLine();
        if(line == "")
        {

        }
    }  
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // ToDo
}
```

Comment: Read each line. If value is not empty, store the value into a List. When you hit the empty space, create the DataHolder pulling the values from the List. Then clean out the List and repeat

Comment: `new DataHolder()` instantiates a new object.  You can perform such an action inside your loop as well as out.  Of course, you need to do something with the new instance (assign it to a variable, put it in a collection, ...) for that to be any use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
File theFile = new File(pathToFile);
try
{
    Scanner fileContent = new Scanner(theFile);
    List<DataHolder> dataList = new ArrayList<DataHolder>();
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(fileContent.hasNextLine())
    {
        stringList.add(fileContent.nextLine());
        if(line.equals(""))
        {
            if (!stringList.isEmpty())
            dataList.add(new DataHolder(stringList));
            stringList.clear();

        }
    }  
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // ToDo
}
```

Comment: While Brian's answer is good, this is the completed code snippet.

Comment: Just a minor comment, you could close the resources.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
if(line == "")
```

is incorrect since you're comparing references. You should use

```
if(line.equals(""))
```

Then you can reliably compare strings, and then re-initialise your DataHolder object in the loop via:

```
if(line.equals("")) {
   data = new DataHolder();
}
```

Presumably you need to store a collection of DataHolders, in which case you would add it to the collection here. Perhaps also investigate `String.trim()`, such that multiple whitespaces don't break your parsing.

Comment: This only provides part of the answer. This doesn't set the variables in DataHolder

Comment: It's not what he's asked for (despite that section being missing in the code)

Comment: It seems like that is what they are asking: `The DataHolder class has variables for 1 2 3 and 4.` and then `DataHolder class should be created for the next 1 2 3 4.`